# SQL database design: many to many relationship between 'accounts' and 'transactions' tables such that a transaction can have 'from' and 'to'

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a many-to-many relationship between two tables: 'accounts' and 'transactions', but with a catch. Every transaction must be related to two accounts, but each of those accounts *must* be specified as either the sender or receiver.

Likewise, each account should relate to all the transactions they are involved in. Is there a best practice database design pattern that solves this problem? I'm using Sequelize with Postgres if that's helpful.

eg:

Accounts

id | name | transactions_sent (Transactions.id) | transactions_received (Transactions.id)

Transactions

id | notes | sender (Accounts.id) | recipient (Accounts.id)

Comment: This should be enough: `Table accounts: id,  name; Table transactions: id, notes, sender references accounts(id), recipient references accounts(id)` . "each account should relate to all the transactions they are involved in" is a query result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simplify your design by creating an additional AccountsTransactions table with composite key from Accounts and Transactions tables and add a new column send_receive_indicator or transaction_type (S - Send/R - Receive) on Transactions table (assuming that each transaction is either send or receive type of transaction). This way you can control your many-to-many relationship on that AccountsTransactions by introducing that new transaction_type column in your query.

Comment: Often called a "linking table" such a pattern is very common in relational databases

Comment: This feels like the right direction. To clarify, does this mean each single Transaction would relate to two rows in AccountsTransactions? e.g:


`id | transactionId | accountId | transactionType

1 | 1 | 1 | Send

1 | 1 | 2 | Receive`

Comment: Yes, there is nothing in the design that's out of the box that would prevent from having more than two transactions for each Account, so I would put a check constraint on AccountsTransaction table or better... control that during your INSERT statement to AccountsTransaction.